# C2DM registration: can I register different users on same application

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I want to register multiple users for same application. Is it possible in Android C2DM? If yes, do we have any documentation link?

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: I want to use Multiple Sender IDs for same application and my client can use any of this id to get registered. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes..why not..please below stesps: 1) Sign up on Google providing your App Name as 'Package Name used for developing application'. It should be in your manifest file. And one of Gmail Id. 2)Send REGISTRATION Intent explained in 'http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/'. 3) Write a receiver which handles RECEIVE and REGISTRATION messages 4) Can cross check ur manifest in above link. Title 'Creating the Manifest' 5) Now when you send REGISTRATION intent, u will get registration id from server. Now get Auth Token from Google server for Gmail id mentioned while signup

Comment: and last step is to write POST request or CURL command to send Registration and Auth Token to Google Server..and you will receive messages